# Update from select with multiple fields?

Tags: mysql, select

I can do the following to insert records into a table from a select on another table:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) SELECT field1,field2 FROM table2
```

Can I do the same with an update ??
Something like this (not working!):

```
UPDATE table SET field1=table2.field1, field2=table2.field2 SELECT field1,field2 FROM table2
WHERE table.field0=table2.field0
```

I know how to do this with only 1 field, but is there a way to do it with multiple fields?

Comment: Possible Duplicate... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/sql-server-update-from-select

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UPDATE table A INNER JOIN table2 B USING (field0)
SET A.field1 = B.field1,A.field2 = B.field2;
```

Comment: where did `field0` come from?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, like this:

```
UPDATE table SET 
field1=(select field1 from table2 WHERE field0=table1.field0)
field2=(select field2 from table2 WHERE field0=table1.field0)
-- WHERE some condition (optional)
```

Comment: Doesn't this run the same query twice, but only return different attributes each time